# How webscraping an svg with Beautifulsoap

Tags: python, svg, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am able to scraper the div where there is the SVG and the script but i am not able to get any results so no svg, just empty div. Do you have any idea how to do this?
I done this:

```
def infrontanalytic(isin):  
     scrapy2 = requests.get('https://www.infrontanalytics.com/fe-en/US0378331005/Apple-Inc-/beta', verify=False).text
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(scrapy2,'html.parser')
        value_scrap2 = soup2.find(class_='panel-body chart-data-inside')
```

later on?

Also is it possible scraping an entire table and return it as HTML table?
example:

```
table=soup2 .find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-condensed table-bordered table-peers'})
Return [html.Div(table)]
```

it give "error loading layout"

Comment: Could you show us the full url of your page?

Comment: please  clarify  substr

Comment: let me know if it is more clear

Comment: This svg was generate by Javascript...

Comment: Is it possible to capture as image?